# Consecutive counting of visible elements on vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a survey to fill out, some questions appear based on different conditions and I need to put numbers for them sequentially.
So all these blocks are just in the template and can be hidden by v-if, and I need the numbering to take into account only the visible elements. Something like

```
<div class="el">
  <div class="el__qty">{{getNum()}}</div> // 1
  ...
</div>
<div class="el" v-if="someCondition">
  <div class="el__qty">{{getNum()}}</div> // 2 if visible
  ...
</div>
<div class="el">
  <div class="el__qty">{{getNum()}}</div> // 2 or 3
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: What **getNum()** is used for ?

Comment: This is just an example for clarity, getNum() should return the number for this item

Comment: You can iterate through all questions and use index as count. Use computed to check which questions to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [css counter](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp). css counter variable are reactive and handle by the browser. so when you hide one of them by `display: none` or remove by `v-if` other number updated automatically.

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;
}

h2::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Using CSS Counters:</h1>
<h2>HTML Tutorial</h2>
<h2>CSS Tutorial</h2>
<h2>JavaScript Tutorial</h2>
```

Comment: Hadn't thought about the CSS approach, I'll give it a try. Thank you!

Comment: Using a before for actual content is a no go for accessibility and SEO: https://accessibleweb.com/question-answer/how-is-css-pseudo-content-treated-by-screen-readers/

Answer (score 0):

When having very similar repeating elements with such logic I would use e v-for and use the index as your counter, similar to:

Your template

```html
<div v-for="(question, index) in questionListFiltered" :key="index">
  <span>{{index}}</span>
  <span>{{element.label}}</span>
</div>
```

Your initial `questionlist` (provided as a prop, or set in data, or retreived from your server etc.)

```json
[
  {
    label: 'First label',
    show: true,
  },
  {
    label: 'Second label'
    show: false,
  },
  {
    label: 'Third label',
    show: true,
  },
]
```

A filtered list, which you can add at initialisation, or use a computed like:

```js
questionListFiltered() => {
  return this.questionList.filter(question => question.show);
}
```

This would result in:

```html
<div key="1">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>First label</span>
</div>
<div key="2">
  <span>2</span>
  <span>Third label</span>
</div>
```